# MacOS Mission Control Keyboard KeyCode

Tags: macos, keyboard, usb, keycode

Does anyone know the hex keycode for MacOS's Mission Control? I know the regular MacOS keycodes can be found at

`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Events.h`

and there is the general [USB HID Consumer Control KeyCodes](http://www.freebsddiary.org/APC/usb_hid_usages.php) but none of these seem to contain the actual hex code for MacOS's Mission Control functionality. It doesn't seem like normal F3 works either.

Answer (score 1):

Try `0x29F` I remember seeing it from a PR on the [QMK Firmware](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware) project. Its in the [HID usage tables](https://usb.org/sites/default/files/hut1_21_0.pdf) under *Consumer Page*

Answer (score 0):

`0xc1` for Mission Control and `0xc2` for Launchpad.

In the event that you are trying to configure a custom keyboard (e.g. QMK firmware and/or VIA) to activate mission control, sending `0xc1` will do it. I don't know why this works and `0x29f` does not despite the latter appearing in industry documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Mission Cotrol: key code `160`

Maybe you can tansfer it to Hex and try again.

[Complete list of AppleScript key codes](https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes) By Christopher Kielty, last updated May 10, 2018